# NavigationDrawer смещается вниз

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь реализовать Navigation Drawer в стиле Material Design, но почему-то он смещается немного вниз. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relative_activity"
    android:background="@color/material_drawer_background">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
        android:transitionName="actionBar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:background="@color/material_drawer_primary"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

////

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Инициализируем Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из Toolbar'a уберите `android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"`

Comment: Точно, спасибо!